# coordinate system, spike graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a spike graph: at each x value I draw a line of length y. I could use `plt.bar` with thin bars. My problem is that I can specify the bar width, but it is given in data coordinates which is inadequate for this purpose. I would like to set the width of the bars to, say 1pt.

```
plt.bar(x,y,width=0.1,align='center',color='black')
```

There is http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html . But this does not answer my question, the x and the y should stay in data coordinates, only the width of the bar should be specified in "true size coordinate", so that putting `transform=...` will not work. The other problem is that I do not find a way to specify data in "true size unit" (pt, cm, inches,...). (The final purpose is to make a pdf file for inclusion in a paper).

EDIT I could use `vlines` instead of `bar`, however, the original question still puzzled me: how can I specify different system coordinate for different parameters of the same object, how can I use true size units?

Answer (score 0):

You could rescale the width each time, something like:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

plt.bar(x, y, width=0.001*max(x))
plt.show()
```

This takes makes the width of each bar always a fraction `0.001` of the total length.